# Uninitialized constant error pertaining to Rails' namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, constants

I posted this question before, but changed some variable names and realized my mistake too late, so this code is unaltered in any way.

Error:

> Routing Error uninitialized constant Firefighters  Rails.root:
>   /Users/Vladdy/Dropbox/dev/firestaff

Here's the relevant, erroring bit from `routes.rb`:

```
  # get '/firefighters/dashboard' => 'firefighters#dashboard'
  namespace :firefighters do
    get '/dashboard'        => 'firefighters#dashboard' # Namely, this one.
    get '/dashboard/:date'  => 'firefighters#dashboard'
    get '/account'          => 'firefighters#account'
    get '/edit'             => 'firefighters#edit'
    get '/approve'          => 'firefighters#approve'
  end
```

If I uncomment line 1, and comment get `/dashboard`, the dashboard loads just fine through `FirefightersController#dashboard`.

I painstakingly checked that all of my model names are singular: `Accountant`, `Engineer`, `Firefighter` and all of my controllers are plural: `AccountingController`, `EngineeringController`, etc.

Here is the stack trace of the error: http://pastebin.com/NpvY2EYy

I hope this is enough information. Once again - SOS! I do no know how to diagnose this problem. If it matters, I'm using ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.5

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get '/firefighters/dashboard' => 'firefighters#dashboard'
```

Works because your controller is

```
class FirefightersController
end
```

These

```
namespace :firefighters do
  get '/dashboard'        => 'firefighters#dashboard' # Namely, this one.
  get '/dashboard/:date'  => 'firefighters#dashboard'
  get '/account'          => 'firefighters#account'
  get '/edit'             => 'firefighters#edit'
  get '/approve'          => 'firefighters#approve'
end
```

Don't work because rails is expecting a module so your controller should be

```
class Firefighters::FirefightersController
```

You could if you're only bothered about the url, not about the folder structure for your app do

```
scope '/firefighters' do
  get '/dashboard'        => 'firefighters#dashboard' # Namely, this one.
  get '/dashboard/:date'  => 'firefighters#dashboard'
  get '/account'          => 'firefighters#account'
  get '/edit'             => 'firefighters#edit'
  get '/approve'          => 'firefighters#approve'
end
```

In which case you could leave your controller as it is.

Comment: Good answer. In which situation is `scope` superior to `namespace`?

Comment: Also, using `scope` seems to have broken my auto generated paths like `firefighters_dashboard_path`. Any tips there?

Comment: Is a firefighter a singular resource?  I.e. Can you see all firefighters or is there just "one" by that I mean say I login as a firefighter, I can only see my stuff, no other firefighters stuff.

Comment: There's gonna be accounting, chiefs, etc, they are not in the routes right now though.

Comment: all under `/firefighters`?  Ok then my other suggestion wouldn't make that much sense.  I was going to suggest a singular resource.  You can do `get '/dashboard'        => 'firefighters#dashboard', as: :firefighters_dashboard`