# Rails namespaced controller uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462137/uninitialized-constant-error-pertaining-to-rails-namespaces) question but the answers there don't work here.

In `routes.rb`

```
scope '/api/ do
  namespace :v1 do
    scope :reports do
      get '/reportXYZ', to: 'reports#reportXYZ'
    end
  end
end
```

In `app/controllers/V1/reports_controller.rb`

```
module V1
    class ReportsController < ApplicationController
      def reportXYZ
        ...
      end
    end
end
```

the error:

`uninitialized constant V1` on Windows only, works fine on ubuntu. How come?

Comment: Your on-disk directory needs to be `v1`, not `V1`. Please fix the syntax errors in your routes file.

Comment: Do you mean it works on Windows and not on Ubuntu?

Comment: The above code works fine on ubuntu and debian but not on windows (interestingly enough also doesn't work the new linux subsystem on windwos 10)

Answer (score 0):

In your routes .rb file instead of writing scope for api write like this

```
namespace :api do

  namespace :v1 do

    scope :reports do
      get '/reportXYZ', to: 'reports#reportXYZ
    end
  end

end
```

And in your controller

```
module api

  module V1

    class ReportsController < ApplicationController
      def reportXYZ
        ...
      end
    end

  end
END
```